# Is there a server side mechanism to determine the login status of a user in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Rather than utilizing JavaScript I would like to know wheter a user is already logged into facebook by a server side call. Is there some mechanism?

I am using the current version of http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/.

fbApp.???

Comment: What do you want to know whether user have logged in to Facebook or whether he have logged in and allowed your facebook app to access facebook?

Comment: If the last then you can see related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760406/authenticate-user-serverside-from-stand-alone-application/4762042

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot ways to do this. The most basic is fbApp.Session == null. If the session is null then there is no user. You should also look at the Authorizer and CanvasAuthorizer classes in Facebook.Web. There are methods on those that will help with authentication. There are lots of documents on the codeplex site. I would suggest giving those a read as well.